# WCF service timing out only when called from an ASP.NET web app

Tags: asp.net, wpf, wcf

I have a few WPF applications that have WCF services with a single function called UpdateValues. I have about 5 applications working, but for some reason one is not. I tested the app using the WCF test application, and it is working correctly, so I believe the error is in the client.

The client is an ASP.NET 2.0 web application. The WCF service is added to the project as a web reference. When executed, the connection times out. The WCF function just contains a single line of code to make a beep, so I know the issue is not a real timeout due to processing time. If the WPF application is not running, the function call fails immediately.

I tried converting the app to .NET 4 and I get the same error.Any thoughts for getting a more detailed error message?

---

I found the issue, for some reason my app.config had changed the binding type to wsHttpBinding instead of basicHttpBinding. Everything is running fine now.

```
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="JobSheetDisplay.IUpdateService">

    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="InkSetupDashboard.IUpdateService">
```

Comment: Try to enable tracing on your WCF service and monitor the trace log for more detailed information. Also try to inspect your request using Fiddler/WireShark and see the raw request and response and the http codes being returned